# Why can't I perform gradients on a variable passed as an argument to a tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, gradienttape

My training loop was giving me the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['noise:0'] when minimizing the loss.

After some tinkering I determined this only happened when the noise variable was being passed as an argument to my loss function which is a `tf.function`. The code below shows that there is no problem when the loss function is not a `tf.function` or when the global noise variable is referenced in the function. It also shows that an error results from trying to perform a gradient on the noise variable when it is used as argument in a `tf.function`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from  tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd 
from tensorflow_probability import bijectors as tfb

constrain_positive = tfb.Shift(np.finfo(np.float64).tiny)(tfb.Exp())
noise = tfp.util.TransformedVariable(initial_value=.1, bijector=constrain_positive, dtype=np.float64, name="noise")
trainable_variables = [noise.variables[0]]
kernel = tfp.math.psd_kernels.ExponentiatedQuadratic()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
index_points = tf.constant([[0]], dtype=np.float64)
observations = tf.constant([0], dtype=np.float64)

# I can train noise when it is passed as an argument to a python function 
def loss_function_1(index_points, observations, kernel, observation_noise_variance):
    gp = tfd.GaussianProcess(kernel, index_points, observation_noise_variance=observation_noise_variance)
    return -gp.log_prob(observations)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    nll_1 = loss_function_1(index_points, observations, kernel, noise)
grad_1 = tape.gradient(nll_1, trainable_variables)
print(grad_1)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_1, trainable_variables))

# I can train noise if it is used in a tf.function and not passed as an argument
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=False)
def loss_function_2(index_points, observations, kernel):
    gp = tfd.GaussianProcess(kernel, index_points, observation_noise_variance=noise)
    return -gp.log_prob(observations)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    nll_2 = loss_function_2(index_points, observations, kernel)
grad_2 = tape.gradient(nll_2, trainable_variables)
print(grad_2)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_2, trainable_variables))

# I can train noise if it is passed as an argument to a tf.function if the tf.function
# uses the global variable
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=False)
def loss_function_3(index_points, observations, kernel, observation_noise_variance):
    gp = tfd.GaussianProcess(kernel, index_points, observation_noise_variance=noise)
    return -gp.log_prob(observations)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    nll_3 = loss_function_3(index_points, observations, kernel, noise)
grad_3 = tape.gradient(nll_3, trainable_variables)
print(grad_3)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_3, trainable_variables))

# I cannot train noise if it is passed as an argument to a tf.function if the tf.function
# the local variable
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=False)
def loss_function_4(index_points, observations, kernel, observation_noise_variance):
    gp = tfd.GaussianProcess(kernel, index_points, observation_noise_variance=observation_noise_variance)
    return -gp.log_prob(observations)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    nll_4 = loss_function_4(index_points, observations, kernel, noise)
grad_4 = tape.gradient(nll_4, trainable_variables)
print(grad_4)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_4, trainable_variables))
```

This code prints:

> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.045454545454545456>]
> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.045413242911911206>]
> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.04537197429557289>]
> [None]

And then it returns the error message:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['noise:0'].

Ideally I would get the performance boost of a `tf.function` so I don't want to use `loss_function_1`. Also, I would like to be able to pass different noise variables to my loss function so I do not want to use the global variable like I do in `loss_function_2` or `loss_function_3`.

Why do I get None when I try to perform a gradient on a variable passed as an argument to a `tf.function`? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't workaround it, it works like that by design.

When you use `tf.function` you're converting the Python code to a static graph (in particular a DAG). This graph has some input nodes and some output nodes.
The input nodes are the parameter of your function and the output nodes are the return values.

Defining a `tf.Variable` inside the function body, or equivalently, passing a `tf.Variable` as a function parameter, means creating a new variable node in the static graph every time you invoke it and creating a new variable every time you call it it's now what you want.

In practice, when you have objects with a state (`tf.Variable` and similar) you can't define them inside a `tf.function`-decorated function, but you have to break the function scope and declare the variable outside it.

Your solution of declaring a global variable is the one to use. A better solution is to refactor your code to be more object-oriented, declaring the variable as a private attribute of a class in order to do not expose the variable object globally.

I covered this behavior in [this article](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/#from-eager-to-tffunction-the-need-to-refactor) where you can find several insights on how to refactor your code and how to think when using `tf.function`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at your article and think about the best way to adapt my code considering this information.